# Proper Memory Management for Objective-C Method

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, sigabrt

I'm programming an iPhone app and I had a question about memory management in one of my methods. I'm still a little new to managing memory manually, so I'm sorry if this question seems elementary.

Below is a method designed to allow a number pad to place buttons in a label based on their tag, this way I don't need to make a method for each button. The method works fine, I'm just wondering if I'm responsible for releasing any of the variables I make in the function.

The application crashes if I try to release any of the variables, so I'm a little confused about my responsibility regarding memory.

Here's the method:

FYI the variable firstValue is my label, it's the only variable not declared in the method.

```
-(IBAction)inputNumbersFromButtons:(id)sender {
    UIButton *placeHolderButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    placeHolderButton = sender;

    NSString *placeHolderString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    placeHolderString = [placeHolderString stringByAppendingString:firstValue.text];

    NSString *addThisNumber = [[NSString alloc] init];
    int i = placeHolderButton.tag;

    addThisNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];

    NSString *newLabelText = [[NSString alloc] init];
    newLabelText = [placeHolderString stringByAppendingString:addThisNumber];

    [firstValue setText:newLabelText];

    //[placeHolderButton release];
    //[placeHolderString release];
    //[addThisNumber release];
    //[newLabelText release];

}
```

The application works fine with those last four lines commented out, but it seems to me like I should be releasing these variables here. If I'm wrong about that I'd welcome a quick explanation about when it's necessary to release variables declared in functions and when it's not. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to release them, but you need them just a little longer than beyond the end of your function.

The solution is called `autorelease`. Just replace `release` with `autorelease` and the objects stay around until the program gets back to the runloop.

When the program gets back there, everybody interested in one of the objects should have sent a `retain` message to it, so the object will not be deallocated when released by the `NSAutoreleasePool`.

**edit** actually, looking at your code, there's a lot more wrong with it. E.g. this:

```
UIButton *placeHolderButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
placeHolderButton = sender;
```

doesn't make sense. First you allocate an object, then assign (a pointer to) it to variable `placeHolderButton`. That's fine.

Then you assign `sender` to that same variable. The reference to the object you just created is now lost.

Not sure if I get what you want, but this would be better:

```
-(IBAction)inputNumbersFromButtons:(id)sender {
    UIButton *placeHolderButton = sender; // this is still a little useless, but ok

    int i = placeHolderButton.tag;
    NSString *addThisNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];

    NSString *placeHolderString = firstValue.text;

    NSString *newLabelText = [placeHolderString stringByAppendingString:addThisNumber];

    [firstValue setText:newLabelText];
}
```

No allocs, so no releases necessary. The strings returned by those functions are already added to the autoreleasepool, so they will be deallocated automatically (if needed).

Comment: oh okay, thanks; just wondering, when does the autorelease pool get released? if this is a question that's unique to every program then it doesn't really matter, just wondering

Comment: @Justin: sorry I jumped too quickly to answering the `release` question to actually look at your code. There were a few issues but I've added a cleaner version to my answer.

Comment: @justin the autorelease pool is drained "at some point in the future"  at the end of the current run loop. the simplest way of looking at this is that anything between curly braces is fine, but if you want to use it outside of the curly braces it is defined in, you need to retain it.

Comment: @MCannon: That's not quite true. Often you autorelease an object before returning it to the caller. In this case, the object is valid for both the scope it is allocated in and also in the scope of the caller.

Comment: thanks, you guys really helped me understand this aspect of obj-c better!

Answer (score 0):

Well. Release them when you are done with them. The sooner the better. Some objects are tricky if you are new to memory management.

Release them in the dealloc method then.

The auto release pool can be handy, some people might disagree according to the performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

you need to release anything containing the word new, alloc/init or copy.

also, you don't need to alloc/init this:

```
UIButton *placeHolderButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
placeHolderButton = sender;
```

another way of doing this is:

```
UIButton *placeHolderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
```

in your version, it is allocating an instance with a retain count of +1, but you are immediately replacing the reference, so there is no way of releasing the memory later.

you are creating a lot of instances with alloc/init, and then replacing their references with autoreleased instances.

you could use

```
    NSString *placeHolderString = [placeHolderString stringByAppendingString:firstValue.text];
```

instead of

```
 NSString *placeHolderString = [[NSString alloc] init];
placeHolderString = [placeHolderString stringByAppendingString:firstValue.text];
```

which is again replacing a manually managed instance created on the first line, with an autoreleased instance on the second.

infact you could replace every alloc/init in this with the factory method and not have to deal with memory at all in it as they would be autoreleased instances.

```
-(IBAction)inputNumbersFromButtons:(id)sender {
    //cast sender as a UIButton to suppress compiler warning, and allow us to reference it as placeholder button
    UIButton *placeHolderButton = (UIButton *) sender;

    int i = placeHolderButton.tag;

    NSString *addThisNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
    [firstValue setText:[firstValue.text stringByAppendingString:addThisNumber]];
}
```

If you look at the class docs for NSString, any method with a + next to it(ie +stringWithString:(NSString *)string) is a class method, don't use these methods on a reference after you have called alloc/init on it.

Comment: okay thanks for the answer that really cleared that up for me

Answer (score 0):

I find it puzzling that you use alloc/init on a UIButton.

I always use the factory methods, e.g.

```
UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

This returns an autoreleased button which I immediately add to its intended parent view.

Can't confirm it right now, but it looks as if the SDK caches UIButton instances and performs some optimizations behind the scenes. Every time I tried to retain a UIButton ivar, performance has degraded (especially when there is many sub views on screen)